# Var with XML after Digest Authentication

Tags: c#, xml, digest-authentication

After a Digest authentication:

```
var resultText = Digester.GrabResponse("/blabla");
```

I have this in the var resulText:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
 <HELLO>
  <time>08:10</time>
  <date>11.08.09</date>
  <temp>35.5</temp>
  <humi>37.7</humi>
 </HELLO>
</response>
```

I tried to fetch the value of the date with XDocument but it didn't work.

Comment: What did you try? What do you mean by `didn't work`?

Comment: With XDocument: Illegal character in path. With a XReader: nullreference. XDocument temp = XDocument.Load(resultText.ToString());
            var date = temp.Descendants("date").First();
            label1.Text = date.ToString();*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really simple: -

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(resultText.ToString());

var date = (from n in xml.Descendants("HELLO")
            select n.Element("date").Value).SingleOrDefault().ToString();
```

You need to use the [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532.aspx) method. Looks like you're passing an XML string as a URI to the `Load` method which obviously wont work.

Comment: Of course. I was loading a string.... XDocument.Load want a URI... Quick and great response. Thank you

Comment: Note: this won't work (will thrown an exception) if the response contains multiple "Hello" elements. It will also throw an exception if the "date" element is missing. The exception will be thrown in the Select for obvious reasons. SingleOrDefault might as well be Single and also, ToString() is redundant here. This might suffice for you but in my opinion this is not a very robust approach.

Comment: @ByteBlast His issue was with using `XDocument.Load` and passing in an XML string rather than a URI, so actually, there's nothing wrong with the answer. The query is a simple example to demonstrate that it works. I don't see more than one `HELLO` element in his sample XML.. If it did, I would obviously not have chosen to use `SingleOrDefault()` to demonstrate and would called something like `.ToList<string>();` instead.